# Using the MIN and MAX of date/time fields in access

Tags: ms-access, datetime

I have a table with the following fields

```
Name:
Location:
Start Time:
End Time:
Total Time:
```

The Name, Location, Start and End Time are extracted from another table, the Total time calculates the difference between the Start and End Time to give the total time spent in that location. The Start and End Time are extracted using a query finding the MAX and MIN time the user was in that location. So for instance a typical result would be:

```
Name: John
Location: A
Start Time: 08:00
End Time: 10:00
Total Time: 2:00
```

The problem is a user could be in one location, go to another, then come back to the same location. For instance another record could be:

```
Name: John
Location: B
Start Time: 09:00
End Time: 09:30
Total Time: 0:30
```

So the user would be in location A 08:00-09:00, then in B 09:00-09:30, then back to A for 09:30-10:00. As the Start and End time are just MIN and MAX the min is always the first time they enter the location and the end is the last time they enter it. Is there a way to amend the time calculation to take into account the 0:30mins spent in location B and deduct this from the time spent in location A. Another note is that there could be up to 5 locations and the user can go back and forth between each of them throughout the day.

Comment: doable, but consider doing it in client-side code rather than sql. what you're wanting requires cross-record comparisons, in various ugly permutations, which will be even uglier to do in sql.

Comment: There are several records for each location before moving on to the next location. What I would like to do is compare the first record with the second. Firstly to see if they are both in the same location and if they are calculate the time difference between them, then append this info to a new table with a location field and time spent field. Is this possible? I'm fairly new to SQL and VBA. Thanks

Comment: I should also point out I want to continue the process and loop through the entire table to extract all the info.

Comment: that's what I mean. sql isn't well suited for inter-record comparisons like that.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use VBA? I don't know what you mean by client-side code???

Comment: yes. vba. sql would be a "server" (as in database server) operation. vba is the client, talking to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.  The following query returns the amount of time each user is at each location:

```
select name, location,
       sum(datediff(s, starttime, endtime)) as TotalTimeInSeconds
from t
group by name, location
```

If you don't have separate records for all the start and end times, you'll need to go back to the original table.

If you can't go back to the original data, then you can do this with a cumbersome self join:

```
select t.name, t.location, 
       min(TotalTime) - sum(t2.totalTime)
from t left outer join
     t t2
     on t.name = t.name and
        t.location <> t2.location and
        t2.starttime between t.starttime and t.endtime
group by t.name, t.location
```

However, I don't recommend this, since it will require a lot of processing.